# How to Integrate Map with JavaFX TableView

Tags: javafx, tableview, treemap

I have a 2 columns TableView that I would like to use to display a content of Map (Key, Value).
The issue is that nothing is getting displayed in the TableView.

```
    @FXML
    private TableView tv;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Map.Entry<Integer, String>, Integer> tcKey;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Map.Entry<String, String>, String> tcValue;
    ObservableMap<Integer, String> map;
    ObservableList<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> observableList;

    int i = 0;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {

        map.put(i++, "value" + i++);
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey() + " Value: " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        map = FXCollections.observableHashMap();
        observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(map.entrySet());
        tv.setItems(observableList);
        tv.getColumns().setAll(tcKey, tcValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These definitions are definitely wrong.

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<Map.Entry<Integer, String>, String> tcKey;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Map.Entry<String, String>, String> tcValue;
```

I would assume the correct definition is:

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<Map.Entry<Integer, String>, Integer> tcKey;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Map.Entry<Integer, String>, String> tcValue;
```

Do note that although you are using `ObservableList` and `ObservableMap`, the actual result would be that the table would not respond to any changes in the `ObservableMap`. If you are expecting the map to change during runtime, then you must do more than this (by using `MapChangeListener`).